# How to change network buffer of network interface to get NIC card errors?

Tags: ethernet, packet-loss

I tried with `sudo ethtool --set-ring eth0 rx 1020`, but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot get device ring settings: Operation not supported`

Is there any other way to change network buffer to simulate NIC card errors and Packet drops.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `netem` queue discipline is for.

For outgoing traffic, just set the qdisc of the outgoing interface to netem:

```
modprobe sch_netem
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem loss 3%
```

You can reset it to normal with

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
```

For incoming traffic, the setup is a little more complicated, please check [netem on incoming traffic](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#How_can_I_use_netem_on_incoming_traffic.3F).

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I think, netem works at network layer. But, I need at NIC card level. If I issue command like "netstat -i", it must show PKT_DROP and Errors.

Comment: There's no way to get the NIC (driver) to simulate failures. At best, you could try setting the ring buffer to 1 (very small), but the driver must support this.

Comment: Thanks Ricky Beam,,,I have one more question, Can we simulate packet errors at NIC(Physical layer) level like hash fails, etc?